# Want to extract RDF from Webpage using Java

Tags: java, rdfa

I want to extract embedded `RDF` (Web semantics) in a webpage and then form a correspoding XML of the `RDF` data, using Java. Any kind of pointer/suggestion/help would be much appreciated.

For example, if there is `RDF` implementation for a `type="Movie"` in a webpage, I would want to form an XML with a Movie tag in it along with its present property  values like `startTime` etc.

Presently I am able to extract data from a DB and form the XML from the Resultset,using Apache Jena API. But I am stuck at how to extract the same from a Webpage

Comment: I recommend you to edit your question adding this comment and remove your comment. This way will be easier to understand what you are asking and the current situation.

Comment: So you want to convert [RDFa](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RDFa) to [RDF/XML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RDF/XML)? I’d guess most RDF tools would be able to handle that. You could ask for a tool recommendation on [softwarerecs.se].

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use software as a service, then [Any23](http://any23.org/any23/) can take some HTML and convert to RDF. If you then want to create SPARQL resultsets from this then load into a Jena Model, and run a query.

Alternatively, if you don't want to use SaaS to extract RDF from HTML/RDFa, then look at [Shellac](https://github.com/shellac/java-rdfa). It works with Jena and includes a CLI.

Comment: Thanks William.. I l look into your suggestions :)